# Inserting 12 hour format using time datatype in MySQL 8.0

Tags: python, mysql, time, alarm

I have a table named 'alarm' and column; 'ID'(A_I) and 'MyTime'. So, I want to store a 12 hour format with AM/PM time datatype instead of 24 hour format in the column MyTime but I don't how to. Can you please help me?

Comment: You cannot STORE by such way. You may RETRIEVE the stored data in this format using proper formatting in output list of the query using DATE_FORMAT() function.

Comment: How to retrieve all the values in the column using TIME_FORMAT??

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for your help.